# Scanning a multi word line and using the first word in an if statement

Tags: java

I want to scan a text file that is filled with data, where the first word decides what kind of object it is and the following words/numbers separated by space are supposed to be data relevant to it.

Lets say something like:

BOAT name

FRIGATE name numberofcannons

FISHINGBOAT name numberoffishermen

and then I have multiple if statements to check what's the first word to make an appropiate object.

If I use nextLine(); how will I be able to use the first word to check for what object am I supposed to make? Is next(); something that would work here?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: Split each line by space and then use the first word to determine the class type.  By the way, why do you want/need to do this?

Comment: Check out String.split(someline).